# zabbix monitor custom service on centos7

Tags: linux, zabbix

I created a service on centos 7 and I tried to configure zabbix to monitor the service, I would like to check if the service is running or not, if not trigger alert.

```
{my_host:net.tcp.service[my_service,127.0.0.1,11990].last()}=0
```

When I check the service from configuration -> hosts -> my_host -> items, I can see the status is Enabled.

the log on the machine shows:

```
7720.364 active check "net.tcp.service[myservice,127.0.0.1,11990]" is not supported
```

Please help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `service_state` item is a [Windows-only agent item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent/win_keys) (and in Zabbix 3.0 it is deprecated in favour of the `service.info` item).

For Linux, you'd probably create a custom item using the [user parameter](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/userparameters) feature. Note that the resulting item must be of the `Zabbix agent` or `Zabbix agent (active)` type. What exactly should your custom item do? That depends on how you would determine that the service is up. You could check connectivity to your service, check output from an initscript or service management daemon and so on.

If you would like to avoid using userparameters, two simple solutions come to mind:

- [check how many processes are running with the specified name using the `proc.num` item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent) (agent item)
- if your service listens on a TCP port, you could [check connectivity to it using the `net.tcp.port` or `net.tcp.service` items, or check whether it listens on the required port using the `net.tcp.listen` item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent) (agent item) - or you could also [check connectivity to that port from the server side using the `net.tcp.service` item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/simple_checks) (simple check item)

For example, to check that something is responding on TCP port 11990 you would use `net.tcp.service[tcp,,11990]` and set the item type to either one of the agent type, or simple check.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I would like to check if the service is running or not, if not trigger alert.

Comment: myservice listen to port 11990, so how should i write this ?
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:11990 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 7868/myservice

Comment: added an example in the answer